# How to get the last 50 element from Firebase in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made a ListView for my chat application. I'm using Firebase but I have a problem:

> It shows every data from the server which slows the loading time drastically.

I would like to make a Query which only shows the last 10-30 or 50 element from the list, but I don't know how to develop it and didn't find enough good answer for me in the [Query Api Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query). It would be better if I could dynamically adjust the number like every other chat app (Viber, Messenger) if I scroll up.
So here is my display implementation:

```
private void displayChatMessages() {
    listOfMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
            R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    listOfMessages.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something from Firebase Documentation

```
// Last 100 posts, these are automatically the 100 most recent
// due to sorting by push() keys
Query recentPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("posts")
        .limitToFirst(100);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: `ref = (DatabaseReference) database.getReference().child(String.valueOf(generateChatID)).limitToLast(25)` doesn't seems working.

Comment: Oh yes,
`Query query = ref.limitToLast(20);` and  `adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<MessageModel>(this, MessageModel.class, R.layout.item_chat_right, query) {...` fixed it!